# Add values to a new row in a dataframe

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe. What I would like to do now is add an extra column with the number of words.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame([['These are two words', 1], ['Two words', 2]], columns=('body', 'ticketID'))
```

So therefore I do this:

```
data['Count'] = ''
for index, i in data.iterrows():
  y = len(i['Content'])
  i['Count'] = y
```

However when I print data now I get dont see any values in count. Any suggestion on what goes wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some things that are wrong with your implementation.

Firstly, in the 2 code blocks, you are using different variables. In the first one, your dataframe is called `df`, while in the second it is called `data`. Is this on accident?

Secondly, your variable `y` does not count the number of words, but simply the length of the string. In order to count the number of words in a string, you can take the `len` of `string.split()`, which will split the string every time it encounters a space. If you want to split on another character, you can simply give the character as an argument: `string.split(',')`.

Finally, pandas dataframes and series have 3 different functions for indexing and selecting data:

- `loc` for label-based indexing
- `iloc` for index-based indexing
- `ix` for mixed indexing

The use of these functions is preferred over standard Python indexing, e.g. replace `df['Count']` by `df.loc[:, 'Count']`. More information about this can be found [in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

So here is a version that does what you would like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['These are two words', 1], ['Two words', 2]], columns=('body', 'ticketID'))

df.loc[:, 'Count'] = ''
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    num_words = len(row.loc['body'].split())
    df.ix[idx, 'Count'] = num_words

>>> df
                  body  ticketID Count
0  These are two words         1     4
1            Two words         2     2
```

There is also a nice Pythonic one-liner by using the `df.apply` function:

```
df.loc[:, 'count'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(row.loc['body'].split()), axis=1)
```